# Socket works in next development mode but does not work after building

Tags: socket.io, next.js

The socket in the Home component works well in development mode but when the next app is built and run it no longer works.

In development, the app is run with `next dev`.

Everything loads up initially and the socket works well updating the UI when it receives data from the socket.

However, once I build the application and run, it no longer works. No errors pertaining to the socket show up. Not even regular logs show up after the Home component is rendered. I build the app with `next build` and then run with `next start -p 3000`

**Client-Side**

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import { Button, Card } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import io, { Socket} from 'socket.io-client'
import {DefaultEventsMap} from 'socket.io-client/build/typed-events'
import CryptoProfilerService from './api/CryptoProfiler'
import { GetStaticPropsResult, GetServerSidePropsResult } from 'next'
import {CryptoProfile} from '../types/cyptoprofile'


import Layout from '../components/Layout'
import CryptoProfileTable from '../components/CryptoProfileTable'

import {GET_CRYPTO_PROFILE_EVENT} from '../utils/socket/events'

function useSocket(url: string) {
    const [socket, setSocket] = useState<Socket<DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap> | null>(null)
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const socketio = io(url, {transports: ['websocket']})
  
      setSocket(socketio)
  
      function cleanup() {
        socketio.disconnect()
      }
      return cleanup
    }, [])
  
    return socket
  }

  

function Home({profiles}: CryptoProfileProps){

  console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CRYPTO_SERVICE_URL)
    const [profiles_, setProfiles] = useState<CryptoProfile[]>([])
   
    const socket = useSocket(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CRYPTO_SERVICE_URL!)

    useEffect(() => {
        function handleGetCryptoProfilesEvent(payload: CryptoProfile[]) {
          console.log(`payload`, payload)
          setProfiles(payload)
        }

        if (socket) {
          socket.on(GET_CRYPTO_PROFILE_EVENT, handleGetCryptoProfilesEvent )
        }
      }, [socket])


    return (
        <Layout>
            <div>
                <h3>crypto profiles</h3>
                { profiles && profiles!.length ? <CryptoProfileTable profiles={profiles_.length == 0 ? profiles : profiles_}/> : (<div>sorry. no profiles to display yet</div>)}
            </div>
    </Layout>
    )
}

export default Home

interface CryptoProfileProps {
    profiles: readonly CryptoProfile[] | null;
  }
  

export async function getStaticProps(): Promise<GetStaticPropsResult<CryptoProfileProps>>  {
    const profiles = await CryptoProfilerService.GetProfile()

    return {props: {profiles}}
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p $PORT",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "next": "10.2.3",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^2.0.3",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^15.6.1",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.8",
    "typescript": "^4.3.2"
  }
}
```

**Build Logs**

```
> next build

info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: no custom webpack configuration in next.config.js https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
info  - Checking validity of types  
(node:1943) [DEP_WEBPACK_MODULE_UPDATE_HASH] DeprecationWarning: Module.updateHash: Use new ChunkGraph API
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
info  - Creating an optimized production build  
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Collecting page data  
info  - Generating static pages (2/2)
info  - Finalizing page optimization  

Page                                Size     First Load JS
┌ λ /                               38.8 kB         104 kB
├   ├ css/616d0a9cbeff74a3bd4f.css  98.1 kB
├   └ css/620d38b77a89b808bc8e.css  108 B
├   /_app                           0 B            65.3 kB
├ ○ /404                            1.24 kB        66.6 kB
└ λ /api/CryptoProfiler             0 B            65.3 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all       65.3 kB
  ├ chunks/framework.2191d1.js      42.4 kB
  ├ chunks/main.71948a.js           19.4 kB
  ├ chunks/pages/_app.cddc9f.js     2.55 kB
  ├ chunks/webpack.189c53.js        994 B
  └ css/fb7e07ce64500530d3fc.css    194 B

λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
●  (SSG)     automatically generated as static HTML + JSON (uses getStaticProps)
   (ISR)     incremental static regeneration (uses revalidate in getStaticProps)
```

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: No I'm not. The socket client won't consume events emitted from the server

Comment: What about the connection, is it created?

Comment: It is not created when running the build but it is created when running in development

Comment: are you getting `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CRYPTO_SERVICE_URL` in the prod mode ?

Comment: On initial startup, GetServerSideProps uses process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CRYPTO_SERVICE_URL to get the initial data however afterwards, I can't access that variable.

Comment: My build logs, show all the console.log() messages put in the components however when I run the build, the socket does not work as expected and I can't access the variables or see the logs when I reload the page.

Comment: getServerSideProps work on the server not on the client. Maybe your client(browser) is not able to create connect because it's not able to find `NEXT_PUBLIC_CRYPTO_SERVICE_URL` 
 do one thing hard code the value for now and try.

Comment: I have hardcoded it and tried but It doesn't help unfortunately

Comment: Apart from that, I don't see any other issue. Can you add logs as well

Comment: Yes, I already added logs and they still won't show up, unfortunately.

Comment: I mean in the question, both server and browser.

Comment: How do you mean please?

Comment: can you edit the question and add logs as well.

Comment: I have attached the build logs please. @RahulSharma

Comment: I have created sample app using socket, Have a look. https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-socketio

Comment: @JosephAkayesi have you tried running `next export` to independently serve and inspect the js files that are being produced? have you ran `next start` after `next build`, opened your browsers devtools, and inspected what JS is being loaded, if any?

Comment: @JosephAkayesi you are also using `getStaticProps` which by using `next` assumes a full static compilation with a serverless system. Have you looked at the Network Inspector for any request errors? the JS console doesn't always show network errors

Comment: Next.js only runs `getStaticProps` during compilation. for Client-Side data, you should try the [`SWR`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#swr) react hook:

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? I am experiencing the same thing and looking for a solution

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem in your code, Not sure am I missing something.

I have created Sample App, Check this out, Hope this will help

https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-socketio

**Server**

```
import { Server } from 'socket.io';

const ioHandler = (req, res) => {
  if (!res.socket.server.io) {
    console.log('*First use, starting socket.io');
    const io = new Server(res.socket.server);

    io.on('connection', socket => {
      console.log('Connected socket.io');
      socket.broadcast.emit('a user connected');
      socket.on('hello', msg => {
        socket.emit('hello', 'world!');
      });
    });

    res.socket.server.io = io;
  } else {
    console.log('socket.io already running');
  }
  res.end();
};

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false
  }
};

export default ioHandler;
```

**Client**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import io, { Socket } from 'socket.io-client'

function useSocket(url: string) {
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState < Socket < DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap> | null > (null)
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url).finally(() => {
      const socketio = io()
      socketio.on('connect', () => {
        console.log('connect')
        socketio.emit('hello')
      });
      socketio.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('disconnect')
      });
      setSocket(socketio)
    });
    function cleanup() {
      socketio.disconnect()
    }
    return cleanup;
  }, []);
  return socket;
}

export default () => {
  const socket = useSocket('/api/socketio');
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [user, setUser] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (socket) {
      socket.on('hello', data => {
        console.log('hello', data)
        setMessage(data);
      });
      socket.on('a user connected', () => {
        setUser('a user connected')
      });
    }
  }, [socket]);
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Socket.io</h1>
      <h1>Socket Message: {message}</h1>
      <p>User Onle Visible when you open in Sencond Tab</p>
      <h1>User: {user}</h1>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: That is the point! It runs when in development mode but does not work when you build and run the build code. For your particular instance, it does not build at all.

Answer (score 0):

according to the socket.io broadcast method description:

> Sets a modifier for a subsequent event emission that the event data will only be broadcast to every sockets **but the sender**.

a simple `socket.emit` underneath the `socket.broadcast` will fix it

Although it doesn't explain why it works in dev and not built projects I've also noticed that it doesn't work in a built next.js project